# SQL Server: having separate tables vs adding columns (db design)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Entree]
(
    [RowId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [FK_InspirationSource] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Type] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PriceRangeType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SoldCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [HolidaySpecial] [bit] NULL,
    [DiscountApplicable] [bit] NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NULL,
    [LastModified] [datetime] NULL,
    [Enabled] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [BirthDate] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [IG_Int1] [int] NULL,
    [IG_Int2] [int] NULL,
    [IG_Int3] [int] NULL,
    [IG_Int4] [int] NULL,
    [IG_Int5] [int] NULL,
    [IG_Int6] [int] NULL,
    [IG_Int7] [int] NULL,
    [IG_Int8] [int] NULL
```

and in C# code, corresponds to a Entree object with the respectable fields. IG_Int s specify bunch of other properties of the entree in cooking process.

Now, we want to have `Derived_Entree` objects. In the code, `DerivedEntree` is an `Entree` too. So `DerivedEntree : Entree`.

`DerivedEntree` has more columns. `ParentEntreeId` (FK to `Entree`), `ExtraProcessingStep`.

So for example, an entree would be "Snail Ravioli" and Derived Entree would be "Broiled snail ravioli".

If there were a separate table, it would be

```
CREATE TABLE [DerivedEntree]
(
    [RowId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FK_Entree] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ExtraProcessingStep] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

and add `FK_DerivedEntree` in `Entree` table.

So whenever a new entree is entered, a row is inserted to the `Entree` table, and when a new `DerivedEntree` is entered, it is inserted to both tables. This is to satisfy the requirement that every Entree has to have a unique Id (which will be a `RowId` in `Entree` table)

Instead of adding a separate table, another option is to add those two columns (`FK_Entree` and `ExtraProcessingStep`) to the `Entree` tables and store them there.

What is a more standard practice? I thought about adding additional table because of `FK_Entree` but perhaps having a foreign key to itself is a common practice?

Comment: There are a few questions in the "Linked" section of the duplicate that may be helpful as well.  Bottom line is there's a tradeoff between data normalization cleanliness and query cleanliness (more complex structure= more complex joins).  You can alleviate the join complexity, however, by adding views.

Comment: @DStanley Hi Stanley, thanks for the reply. I thought this question might be more specific because this is a case where a table already exists and is used. I was wondering if adding a column fk_ to itself is a common/valid practice vs adding a new table.

Comment: Sure - a foreign key to itself is a common practice when dealing with heirarchical data.

Answer (score 0):

Melissa, this question is not answerable and depends heavily on your desired usage of the system.

Here are your two main design options:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_schema

> The snowflake schema is similar to the star schema. However, in the
>   snowflake schema, dimensions are normalized into multiple related
>   tables, whereas the star schema's dimensions are denormalized with
>   each dimension represented by a single table. A complex snowflake
>   shape emerges when the dimensions of a snowflake schema are elaborate,
>   having multiple levels of relationships, and the child tables have
>   multiple parent tables ("forks in the road").

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema

> The star schema separates business process data into facts, which hold
>   the measurable, quantitative data about a business, and dimensions
>   which are descriptive attributes related to fact data. Examples of
>   fact data include sales price, sale quantity, and time, distance,
>   speed, and weight measurements. Related dimension attribute examples
>   include product models, product colors, product sizes, geographic
>   locations, and salesperson names.
>
> A star schema that has many dimensions is sometimes called a centipede
>   schema.[3] Having dimensions of only a few attributes, while simpler
>   to maintain, results in queries with many table joins and makes the
>   star schema less easy to use.